Entra Azure Access token is too large for sending to other API's .NET 8
We are implementing Entra OIDC flow in our .NET 8 application.
Currently we are able to login.
The ID token contains all our approles (about 300). So far so good.
When we retrieve the access token (bearer) for calling our back-end API we get the access token which also contains the AppRoles.
var token = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new List<string>() { "api://a8cd497b-be63-4f16-9bde-*****/all" })

The result of this is a really big JWT token. When we include this token in the header of our future requests we get following error:

HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long

Is there a way to fix this, or exclude the roles from the access token, or other ways?
Thanks in advance

Did you try with ./default

What is ./default exactly?

Ok I tried with ./default but now I'm not using the OBO flow anymore.

For clarity, the generated access token seems correct. But it's very big due to many roles. I wish there was a way to encode the roles claim to base64 and include it in the token this way

Are you able to get the token  value and getting error in displaying? or getting error in var token = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new List<string>() { "api://a8cd497b-be63-4f16-9bde-*****/all" }) this line itself ?

Yes, I'm able to get the token and display it (and decode it in jwt.io).

But when I'm sending this token to my api I get the above error.

Did you try any encryption method ?

What do you mean exactly?
Encrypt the token, send it, and decrypt it on the api side?
